# Display current subroutine/subprogram in statusline

Tags: vimscript, statusline, filetype-fortran

I am currently coding fortran, and I have huge "subprograms" (called "*subroutine*" in fortran). So I would like the name of the current subroutine (the subprogram my cursor is currently in) to be displayed in my statusline.

This is what a subroutine looks like in fortran (this should make my trick clearer):

```
subroutine my_subprogram(args)
   stuff going on 
end
```

I found the following trick, currently in my .vimrc file.

```
function! SubName()
   let current_line = line(".")  " I store the current line number 
   ?subroutine                   " searches the previous occurence of "subroutine"
   let title_line = line(".")    " stores the line where the subroutine title is
   execute ":".title_line        " go to the line where the title is
   normal! eeb                   " put the cursor on the 2nd word :  "my_subprogram"
   let sub_name = expand("<cword>") " extract the subroutine name in a variable
   execute ":".current_line      " come back to the initial position
   return sub_name
endfunction
```

Then I put the function in my statusline and it works *almost* fine : the name is displayed but... **I cant do `/` searches anymore !** It highlights found text but I can't scroll to the next occurences of the pattern I'm looking for.

I guess this might be because the function is permanently called and thus Vim permanently performs researches because of the `?subroutine` line.

(This is my first time trying to vimscript, so there are probably some ugly things there that you may want to correct -- please do not hesitate !)

Comment: Rather than a function, you can use key mappings simply.

Comment: I did at first, that's how my .vimrc is set at the moment : I press my shortcut each time I want to know in which subroutine I am. But I wanted it to be automatic and permanent (hence the displaying in the statusline). 

Or maybe I am misunderstanding you ?

Comment: Not what you wer looking for, but as an idea: you could go for https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar. It'll show you where you're in the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
function! SubName() abort
    let prev_sub_line_num = search('subroutine ', 'bcnW')
    return matchstr(getline(prev_sub_line_num), 'subroutine \zs\w\+')
endfunction

set stl+=%{SubName()}
```

---

```
    let prev_sub_line_num = search('subroutine ', 'bcnW')
```

Call the `search()` function to look for the pattern `subroutine`.
In the 2nd argument, 4 flags are passed to `search()`:

- `b` look backward instead of forward
- `c` accept a match at current cursor position
- `n` don't move the cursor
- `W` don't wrap around the end of the file

So, `search()` returns the number of the line where the previous `subroutine` text is found.
This number is stored in the variable `prev_sub_line_num`.

```
return matchstr(getline(prev_sub_line_num), 'subroutine \zs\w\+')
```

Then, `matchstr()` is called, which looks for the pattern `subroutine \zs\w\+` inside the contents of the line `prev_sub_line_num`, and returns the matching text.

2 arguments are passed to `matchstr()`:

- `getline(prev_sub_line_num)` which gets the contents of the previous line where `subroutine` was found
- the pattern `subroutine \zs\w\+` which matches the word (`\w\+`) just after the text `subroutine`. In a regex, `\zs` allows you to set the start of a match. Here, it allows you to get rid of `subroutine`, even though it's inside the pattern.

Note that the contents of the statusline including the expression `SubName()` will be evaluated on every screen update, which could slow Vim down.

Comment: nice, do you know if those flags exists for the `/`/`?` also ?

Comment: @Nobe4 I don't know for the `c` and `n` flags, but you can get something similar to `W` by typing `:set nowrapscan`. You can also apply some offsets after a `/` / `?` search. For example, `/foobar/e` should position the cursor on the end of the next `foobar` (`r`), and `?foobar?s+3` should position the cursor on the third character after the start of the previous `foobar` (`b`). Other than that, I don't know if you can tweak the behavior of a search.

Comment: Wow. This shows how much I have to learn about vim. Thank you very much, I will test it asap.