# Statusline function only displayed when sourcing .vimrc

Tags: vimscript, vimrc, statusline

I have a function that detects the name of the subroutine* my cursor is in, thanks to [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7442/7128).

```
function! SubName() abort
   if &syntax !='fortran'
      return ""
   endif
   let prev_sub_line_num = search('subroutine ', 'bcnW')
   return matchstr(getline(prev_sub_line_num), 'subroutine \zs\w\+')
endfunction
```

It is used in my statusline as follows :

```
if &syntax== 'fortran'
   set statusline+=%8*\ %{SubName()}\ 
endif
```

It works well, excepted that I have to *source my `.vimrc` file upon opening VIM every time I want it to work*. I would like some sort of 'autocmd' that would save me this sourcing at each session I'm starting -- and also understanding what's happening !

(I naively tried `autocmd BufWritePre,BufRead *.f* call SubName()` but it does not seem to change anything).

**Edit**

user9433424 gave me an [explanation as well as a solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7921/7128) through taking away the test around the `set statusline` command.

It works, but now when opening a *non-fortran* file I get a small empty zone in my statusline with color highlight `%8`... And it's a little ugly. I understand why but I'd love to get rid of it !

(Maybe I could just add a `else` case in my `SubName` function like :

```
else
   return "You're awesome !"
endif
```

but it was not really my initial plan !)

**Edit II**

As asked by user9433424, here is the part of my `.vimrc` that concerns my statusline.
[image: Here one can see the little empty space in purple]

*"subroutine" is the name for Fortran's subprograms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'syntax'` is an option which is local to a buffer, I don't think you should test it inside your `vimrc` but inside your function `SubName()`, which you already did. So, you probably don't need the test around `set statusline+=%8*\ %{SubName()}\`.

Inside your `vimrc`, you could simply write this:

```
function! SubName()
   return &syntax !=# 'fortran' ? '' : ' ' . matchstr(getline(search('subroutine ', 'bcnW')), 'subroutine \zs\w\+') . ' '
endfunction

set statusline+=%8*%{SubName()}
```

---

The reason why it didn't work is because during the startup, when Vim sources your `vimrc`, it's not in the context of a `fortran` buffer. The test fails and no `%{SubName()}` item is added to the statusline.

The test has to be performed in the context of the current buffer, inside the function.

---

The reason why, when opening a non-fortran file, you get a small empty zone in your statusline with color highlight `%8` is because you didn't move the spaces around the item from your `'statusline'` option to your function.

In your previous code, you had this line:

```
set statusline+=%8*\ %{SubName()}\
```

The backslash and space before and after the `%{SubName()}` item shouldn't be there, they should be inside your function where the syntax test is realised.

In the code I wrote earlier, there's this line:

```
   return &syntax !=# 'fortran' ? '' : ' ' . matchstr(getline(search('subroutine ', 'bcnW')), 'subroutine \zs\w\+') . ' '
```

Before and after the `matchstr()` function, there's `' ' .` and `. ' '`. These are the original spaces which will be added around your subroutine name, but only if you're inside a fortran file.

Comment: Does your new syntax of the `SubName` function changes anything ? I tried it but it does not change much (except the size of my statusline zone).     
Taking off the test around `set statusline` did the trick, thanks, but now I have a little empty zone with the `%8` color in my statusline when opening a non-fortran file. It would be even better if I could get rid of it.

Comment: @Feffe No it doesn't change anything, it's just shorter. The only difference is a space before and after the name of the subroutine inside the function, because I saw there were two spaces inside your code to separate the name from the rest of the information. I don't have a little empty zone with the `%8` color in my statusline when opening a non-fortran file. I'm sorry but I don't understand why you have this zone. It shouldn't be there if you move the spaces inside the function, where the test is realised. Could you give me a link of your complete statusline configuration?

Comment: I added it to my question, tell me if you'd rather have a text file.

Comment: I should have copied your version of the `set statusline`. Thank you for your patience and explanations.